# Apply inline css for antd Table scrollbar

Tags: reactjs, scroll, antd

How to apply inline css for the scroll bar? I need to change default width and color of scroll of the antd Table.

```
 <Table style={{ width: '100%' }} scroll={{ y: 80 }}
          pagination={false}
          columns={columns}
          dataSource={data} />
```

Answer (score 2):

To Apply styles to antd Table scroll bar or any CSS we can achieve it by selector of where the data is present

> ant-table-content

You can specify the class and use webkit-scrollbar for desiging

```
.ant-table-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
    /* width of the entire scrollbar */
}

.ant-table-content::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: orange;
    /* color of the tracking area */
}

.ant-table-content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: blue;
    /* color of the scroll thumb */
    border-radius: 20px;
    /* roundness of the scroll thumb */
    border: 3px solid orange;
    /* creates padding around scroll thumb */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the idea of how to do it from the answer above but my solution was different. I used devTools to find that pseudo property but mine was under `.ant-table` not `.ant-table-content`

Perhaps we are on different versions of antd?

This works for v3.15.1:

```css
.ant-table::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: blue !important
}

.ant-table::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is worked for me on v5.7.0 :

```
<div>
<style>
      {`
      div::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 6px;
        height: 6px;
      }
      div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: transparent;
      }
      div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: #888;
      }
      `}
    </style>
<Table /> // ant table component
</div>
```